# Filter Categories in Wordpress framework

Tags: wordpress, filter, categories, portfolio

I am working on a project where I have to create two dropdown menus and populate them with categories; subcategories actually.

I have two main categories and I want to populate the menus with their subcategories comparing the parents.

```
<select>            
    <option data-filter="*"><?php echo __('All', 'Avada'); ?></a></option>
    <?php foreach($portfolio_taxs as $portfolio_tax_slug => $portfolio_tax_name): ?>
    <?php if($portfolio_category = 'taste') ?>
    <?php { ?>
    <option data-filter=".<?php echo $portfolio_tax_slug; ?>" ><?php echo         $portfolio_tax_name; ?>                   
    <?php } ?>
    </option>                   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Nothing seems to be working.
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to do what I wanted. The solution was to get the terms of the taxonomy:

```
$ideas_terms = get_terms('portfolio_category', array
       ( 'orderby' => 'count', 
         'hide_empty=> 0, 
         'parent'=>13 
       ) 
);
```

This returns an array with all element with

> parentID == 13

Then to call the other elements of the array you have to use:

```
<?php foreach($ideas_terms as $term): ?> 
   <option data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" href="#"> 
   <?php echo $term->name; ?>
   </option> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```